# CSS file is failing to load for my child theme. WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The website is http://Truepressmusic.com, what weird is some of the styling is working but the error message persists. The file is in its place and is opening in chrome.

error message:

> GET
>   http://truepressmusic.com/wp-content/themes/responsivepro-child/style.css
>   404 (Not Found)

Here is the import for the CSS file placed at the top of `style.css`.

```css
@import url("../responsivepro-child/style.css");
```

No idea what to do.. If anyone has ideas I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This means that there is an incorrect path specified that is trying to reference your css file. You can right-click on the page and select 'view source'. From that window you will see where it is looking for css files and whether or not you get to anything when you click on them tells you if the path to them is correctly specified.

What is the link to the exact page you are trying to load?

Answer (score 1):

You got part of the URL wrong. Rather than `/responsivepro-child/` is should be `/responsivepro_child/`:

http://truepressmusic.com/wp-content/themes/responsivepro_child/style.css?ver=1.0.0.5

Comment: I fixed the link and site works perfectly on safari. No other browser is styling the page correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: It's working OK for me in Chrome. What do you think is not loading? Make sure to refresh the browser and clear the cache, if necessary.